# Player can jump twice. | Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code, the player is only supposed to jump once. But the player jump, and "IsGrounded" i still true, until the player jump again. Can anybody pls help?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player_controller : MonoBehaviour {

    public int speed = 5;

    public Vector3 jump;
    public int jumpForce = 2;

    public bool isGrounded;
    Rigidbody rb;

    private string JumpButton = "Jump";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
       transform.Translate(speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime, 0f, speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `isGrounded` logic is flawed. You are not even setting it to `false` the correct way.

Comment: I'd guess the OnCollisionStay ticks a few times after you set it to false.

Comment: @Maakep How do I fix this?

Comment: Set it to true OnCollisionEnter if collider == ground